# IDEA has action "Apply patch from clipboard". How to put patch to clipboard?

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control

IDEA has action "Apply patch from clipboard".

It's always inactive for me.

How to put patch to clipboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature [is implemented](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156374) in [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).

Answer (score 4):

To apply the patch open the menu in Android Studio

`VCS` -> `Apply Patch from Clipboard...`

And automatically will find the file to be patched.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one way: after creation a patch file, need to open it in text editor and copy the context to clipboard.

Only then this action becomes active.